# Map null values to default using builder with MapStruct

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, mapstruct, protobuf-java

I want to map field from `Source` to `Target` class, and if the source value is `null`, I would like to convert it to default value based on  the data type ("" for strings, 0 for numeric types etc.). For setting the values, I am not using regular setters, but builder (with [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), so the names of the methods is `newBuilder()` and `build()`).

```
class Source {
    private final String value; // getter
}

class Target {
    private final String value;

    public static Builder newBuilder() {return new Builder()}

    public static class Builder {
        public static setValue() {/*Set the field*/}
        public static Target build() {/*Return the constructed instance*/}
}
```

My mapper looks like this:

```
@Mapper(
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT,
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT
)
public interface TargetMapper {
    Target map(Source source);
}
```

The generated mapper implementation with this code calls `target.setValue(source.getValue())`, instead of performing the null check and setting default value if source returns `null`. The interesting part is when I add the following annotation to the `map` method, the null check is present in the implementation.

```
@Mapping(source="value", target="value", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT)
```

Is this a bug in MapStruct with builders, or am I missing some configuration to be ably to set the null mapping as a default policy, instead of duplicating it on all field mappings?

EDIT: For some reason, adding `nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS` to the class level `@Mapper` annotation adds the null check, but does not explicitly set the value, just skips the call to `setValue`. For protobuf, this is okay, since this functionality is in the library, but for other implementations the field would remain null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Mapping(source="value", target="value", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT)`

applies to update method (so methods that have the `@MappingTarget` annotated parameter

There's no real counterpart for regular methods: 
1. `NullValueMappingStragegy` applies to the bean argument itself.
2. `NullValueCheckStragegy` does perform a check on bean properties, but does not return a default.

Naming is not really brilliant and it has a long history. We still have the intention to align this one day.

A solution would be to use an Object factory creating the builder target object and pre-populate it with default values and then let MapStuct override these one day.

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```java
@Mapper(
    // to perform a null check
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS
)
public interface TargetMapper {
    Target map(Source source);
}

// to create a pre-defined object (defaults set a-priori). Not sure
// whether this works with builders.. just try
@ObjectFactory
default Target.Builder create() {

   Target.Builder builder = Target.newBuilder();
   builder.setValueX( "someDefaultValue" );
   return builder;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is now clear to me! The solution with ObjectFactory would be very verbose for me, so I will stick with just using nullValueCheckStrategy, which is enough for me in this case, since the protobuf builders always set default if the setter is not called.