# Mapper function null parameter check

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct in combination with Lombok and builder pattern.
I have an issue that MapStruct is doing an explicit null check of all parameters inside the generated mapper function and does an early exit in case all parameters are null, e.g.:

```
// Object A
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class SourceA{
    private int a;
}

// Object B
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class SourceB{
    private int a;
}

// Object C
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class SourceC{
    private int a;
}

// Object Target
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class Target{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
}

// Mapper
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface Mapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "a", source = "sourceA.a"),
            @Mapping(target = "b", source = "sourceB.a"),
            @Mapping(target = "c", source = "sourceC.a")
    })
    Target toTarget(SourceA sourceA, SourceB sourceB, SourceC sourceC);
};

// mapstruct impl
// Auto Generated by MapStruct!
public class MapperImpl implements Mapper {
    public Target toTarget(SourceA sourceA, SourceB sourceB, SourceC sourceC){
        // Problamatic line
        if (sourceA == null && sourceB == null && sourceC == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Target.Builder builder = Target.builder();
            // map objects
            return builder.builder();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that MapStruct does not implement the full null check. It should setup the whole builder even if all parameters are null and call build at the end that the builders null checks takes place (if there are any).

Comment: You might want to elaborate and expand your example to show how you're combining lombok and mapstruct. Also, what should mapstruct do if everything that's passed is null?

Comment: lombok is not an issue here. I just wanted to say that I am rely on Builder pattern inside mapstruct. I just use lombok - mapstruct  - databinding plugin in maven.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on how _exactly_ you're using both. There might be a subtle problem which your description doesn't convey. Also, this feels like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. you are looking for a way to configure/adapt mapstruct when the actual cause might be an error in the design itself (or the usage of mapstruct).

Comment: just updated the example. Its just about mapstruct preventing full null check

Comment: So `toTarget()` isn't called if all the sources are `null`? Isn't this the same as you manually checking this and returning `null` explicitly?

Comment: toTarget in MapperImpl is generated by Mapstruct. It places the "if all are null" check everytime in the generated function.

Comment: In that case, would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884866/map-null-values-to-default-using-builder-with-mapstruct

Comment: no, since null value checks are done either on properties on source object or on source object self when trying to apply null to target. the option does not have any affect to parameter check of the mapper function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, always create a default instance of the target object you need to use the `NullValueMappingStrategy`.

On your mapper you can do `@Mapper(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)` when you do that the generated code should look something like:

```
public class MapperImpl implements Mapper {
    public Target toTarget(SourceA sourceA, SourceB sourceB, SourceC sourceC){

        Target.Builder builder = Target.builder();
        // map objects
        return builder.builder();
    }
}
```